# Mailboxer stripping inline css when saving to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mailboxer

I'm using tinymce which applies inline css for text colour etc. My issue is, if I apply colour change to some text tinymce produces the following:

```
<p><span style="color: #ff0000;">asdf</span></p>
```

When I save this reply:

```
reply = current_user.reply_to_sender(receipt[messageIndex], params[:body])
```

... and check the database it has:

```
<p><span>asdf</span></p>
```

If I simply print params[:body] everything is fine, it's just the result of the save

Am I missing something here. I tried this without tinymce i.e. just put the html directly into a textarea with the same results so it's not tinymce.

Also I have tinymce in other areas of my app and it works fine with the same code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that it's down to the default behaviour of the reply_to_sender method in Mailboxer where sanitize_text is set to true

```
(Object) reply_to_sender(receipt, reply_body, subject = nil, sanitize_text = true, attachment = nil)
```

changing my method call to the following fixed this:

```
reply = current_user.reply_to_sender(receipt[messageIndex], params[:body], nil, false, nil)
```